# FirebaseAuth Signout Exhibiting Odd Behavior

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm running into a weird behavior where my logout functionality works partially. When I press the logout button, it calls FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(). No errors are thrown, but it doesn't redirect to the Login Screen.

In main.dart, I have a StreamBuilder that is listening to authStateChanges, so I am expecting the the app to be redirected to the Login Screen when logout is pressed. It seems that when pressing Logout, it does notify an authStateChange, but I have to close/kill the app first and reopen it to have the app redirect to the Login Screen.

Alternatively, I tried to navigate to the Login Screen after the Logout button was pressed (a Navigator call after "await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance .signOut()") which works. However, the issue with this is when I try to login, it doesn't redirect me to the Splash Screen, instead it stays on the Login Screen() even though the login is successful. Likewise, once I close/kill the app and reopen it, it will be redirected to the Splash Screen.

So the weird behavior I'm seeing is that I have to close/kill the app first and reopen it to have the Logout function work...

```
//Logout Button on Logout Page
ElevatedButton.icon(
      icon: Icon(
       Icons.logout,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      label: Text('Logout'),
      onPressed: () async {
        await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signOut()
            .catchError((error) {
          print(error.toString());
        });
      },
    )
//StreamBuilder in Main
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (BuildContext ctx, userSnapshot) {
            if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
              return SplashScreen();
            }
            return LoginScreen();
          },
        ),
```

Comment: If you `print(userSnapshot)` in your `authStateChanges` builder, what does it print when you sign out?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that even though the auth.FirebaseAuth.instance     .signOut() is executed successfully, the StreamBuilder doesn't detect a change. I put in print statement prior to the return statements and nothing is getting printed after logout is pressed...